# addClass and removeClass based on position of single page design

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the confusion.  Basically I am attempting to have scrollable aware active states for the target links I have in the header.  Since this is a one page design, as the user scrolls the page I would like the main navigation to switch to an active state as they pass that targeted section on the page.  Right now I am simply using code to identify the target ID and animate.  Not sure how to tweak it to addClass and removeClass based on scroll position.

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var $target = $(this.hash);
  $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if ($target.length) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 60;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
          if (!location.hash) window.location += target;
      });
  }
}
```

});
});

Comment: I'm not sure what question you are actually asking. Could you clarify what you are asking please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you want to do, but I'm not 100% sure so I'm putting this in a comment. You could get the offsets for the headers and then as you scroll, check to see if the offset is between that offset and that offset + the viewport height.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something similar to this:
http://nordkapp.fi/

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bit of a work in progress and someone else might be able to suggest improvements but I think this is what you wanted?
http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/5wzXL/

One thing you'd definitely want to add is a debounce or throttle on the windows scroll event.   I'll update this once I get a bit more time.  It might help if you posted some of your HTML markup.

---

I've created an update which removes some of the hard coded values from the above example http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/5wzXL/1/

---

Ok hopefully final edit http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/5wzXL/3/.  You might need to hit the run button again to get it working.

Comment: Thanks Nicky! To be honest I think I understand the first example more.  Since I am using this for a fixed main navigation there would only be one instance of the links. The HTML for the navigation is simply on DIV containing the 4 list items. The only thing that makes it unique is being fixed the content flows under the list (like an iFrame). As each piece of the target content passes the fixed header, the link in that header would turn active.

Comment: Ok I've updated it to what I think you want.  Its based on what I've had before and a few things I learned from that example you put up.

Comment: Hey Nicky - sorry for the late reply.  Thanks for working on this.  It seems to work fine in your example but I still can not get it to add and remove a class for the current state once I add it to my code.  Prior to seeing this reply, I have been looking into how http://www.shopify.com/contest does it.  I copied their code (just for testing) and it still will not add and remove the class.  Obviously there is something I am missing here.

Comment: Yeah it might be something to do with your markup.  If you can post up a slimmed down version of your html and javascript I can see whats wrong.

Comment: My markup is simple..<div id="mainNav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#work" id="ourWork">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" id="aboutUs">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services" id="ourServices">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#footer" id="contactUs">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

Comment: Ok well I'll modify my example to use this markup here.  You will need to nest your ul in a sub div that you can move around... at least given my knowledge of css. I have another fiddle which does a similar thing which you can also check out here - http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/5wzXL/3/